# How to pass an array or vector to my c# function from XSLT File Umbraco

Tags: c#, xml, xslt, umbraco7

I'm using Umbraco V 7.5.4, and I have some files which are XSLT.
One of them has a "select"  of html which has a for-each within it that creates the options dynamically according to how many items were brought.

I would like to get those items and put them in a array or vector which can be passed to my c# function that will remove accents and then return a vector.
This vector will have no accents so that I can create the options.

Does anybody have any idea how I can do it ?

I'm really new to Umbraco and I got this project already done, so I'm just doing some fix on it.

Here's the select

```
<select class="form-control" id="cidade" name="cidade">
    <option value="">Selecione</option>
    <xsl:for-each select="$currentPage//*[@isDoc and @nodeType = 1000 and not(cidade=following::cidade)]">
        <xsl:sort select="cidade" order="ascending" data-type="text"/>   
    <option value="{cidade}"><xsl:value-of select="cidade"/></option>         
    </xsl:for-each>
</select>
```

Here's my C# function

```
<msxsl:script language="C#" implements-prefix="user"> 
  <msxsl:assembly name="Design" />
  <msxsl:using namespace="Design" />   

  <![CDATA[       

   public static string ResolverCidades()
   {
         string[] palavras = null; //receive a vetor
         var testar = new Design.Help.Helper().ResolverNomeCidades(palavras);
    var concatenar = "";
        foreach(var item in testar){
            concatenar += item + " ";
         }
return concatenar;
  }

]]>
```

So what I'm doing in this function is receiving a vector, removing the accents from each, concatenating all of them, and returning the result as a string.

Answer (score 1):

It *sounds* like your real problem is that you need to generate the ASCII-only version of strings that contain accented characters.  I'm not familiar with Umbraco, but from your sample above, it's clear that you can use XSLT -- so you don't need C# at all.

This appears to be the key line:

```
<option value="{cidade}"><xsl:value-of select="cidade"/></option>
```

If you need the unaccented strings for the `value` attribute, change this:

```
value="{cidade}"
```

... to this:

```
value="{translate(cidade, 'áàãéèíìóòúù', 'aaaeeiioouu')}"
```

The potentially tricky part is ensuring that the `áàãéèíìóòúù` string contains ***all*** of the accented characters in your input, and that the `aaaeeiioouu` string has the unaccented versions at exactly the same string positions.  For instance, if your accented string in the `translate()` call contains `ñ` as the sixth character, then your unaccented string must contain `n` as the sixth character, or you will get weird results.

Read more about the `translate()` XSLT function here:

- https://www.w3.org/TR/xpath-functions-30/#func-translate

The `translate()` function is supported in XSLT 1.0, and should thus be supported by any standards-compliant XSLT 1.0 processor.

Comment: I will need to preserve the accented one for compatibility.

There's a button when I click on it , it submit the selected item in the "select", There are itens with accents and not which mean the same thing. if I remove completely from my list I will not be able to receive the result of those accented when I submit.

Ex:
  my array = ["São Paulo", "Sao Paulo"] , there are users which are registered in "Sao Paulo" and there are other in "São Paulo".
If I omit "São Paulo" when I submit only those in "Sao Paulo" will show up.

Sorry for my bad english.

Comment: What I Want to do is when I submit, it will search for the selected one in a type of database which when I submit even though it's showing "Sao Paulo" it also considers those one which are from "São Paulo"

Comment: @joab -- It's still not clear to me what you need.  Given my understanding of HTML `<option>` elements, the `value` attribute is what goes to the database -- due to database design constraints, these must often be ASCII-only -- `Sao Paulo` in your example.  The string contained within the `<option>...</option>` tags is what the user sees, which would presumably need to be the accented string -- `São Paulo` in your example.  This is what my sample code above would produce.